# How to Publish a Time Aware Mosaic dataset as an ImageService with Temporal component?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, spatio-temporal-data, image-service

I have a [Time Aware Mosaic dataset](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Time_in_a_mosaic_dataset/009t000001vs000000/) , which contains 5 rasters. I have entered the dates for the given rasters, by adding a Text Field with the dates. (The dates of the images are from 3/1/2013 to 3/5/2013)

The Mosaic dataset works great with the Time Slider window in ArcMap. But when I publish it to ArcGIS Server as an Image Service (through ArcCatlog), I do not see the correct Time Extent on the REST end point. The REST end point shows the Time Info as:

> Time Info:
>
> Time Extent: [2013/01/01 00:00:00 UTC, 2013/01/01 00:00:00 UTC]
>      Time Reference: N/A

What steps have I missed? Where do you set the Time Extent/Time Reference while publishing the image service?

My Configuration: ArcGIS Dekstop 10.0 (ArcInfo)+ ArcGIS Server Advanced+ Image Extension

Comment: The help page for serving time-aware layers in [10.1](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Serving_time_aware_layers/005z00000013000000/) is more useful.  It seems the extent is set in the slider when published.

Comment: @gm70560 That article is for layers in a Mapservice, and not much help for an ImageService.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you are missing time format. If you are using DateTime Field for "Start Time Field" and "End Time Field", you don't need to take care about "Time Value Format". But if you are using Text Field, then the time string must be same as "Time Value Format".

Please check [Mosaic Dataset Properties]Dialog > [Default]Tab.
[image]
In this case, "TIME" is Text type field and time format must be YYYY/MM/DD. So time values  will be such as "2013/03/05".

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Looks Promising! Let me try this and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks a Lot! This has worked out just fine. If You don't mind, I'll like to keep this question open for a day or two, so as to get other answers if any.

Comment: I'm looking forward to meet more good answers. :-)